# How to join to a stored procedure which accepts input dynamically in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which accepts integers as the input and generates output which includes var1 as one of the output. I am trying to JOIN xyz_table to the output of this stored procedure. But the problem is I need to supply the integer value before calling this stored procedure so that I can join to the results sets dynamically.

The query looks something like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM xyz_table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Call_Date_Rate_Proc(t1.idx) ON var1 = t1.idx
WHERE t1.idx IN (12100,78218)
```

But whenever I run this I get an error

> Invalid column idx

Somehow it fails to recognize this variable.

Comment: A procedure has no return value, you need a function. Also, you can not use a function in a query that way; you probably may need a [pipelined function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions)

Comment: You can use a function in the column list but would need to have a function that returns a table source to use it's output as a table. This would be a pipelined function as @Aleksej has mentioned.

Comment: pipelined functions aren't the only option.  non pipelined functions that return table types are also possible.  They just don't have the same performance benefits as pipelined functions.

Comment: the proc does return value . I do it by using PIPE in SQL Script for streaming a cursor.    If I execute the below query I do get the output.  The problem I am facing is how do I call the proc such that it accepts the input column t1.idx    E.g.  select * from Call_Date_Rate_Proc(12100)

Comment: A procedure can have OUT parameters, NOT return values; a function can return values. It would be more useful if you could post some sample data and desired result, explaining the behaviour you need from your code.

Comment: Like everyone else said, use a function. You can't call procedures in Sql, only functions.

Comment: Here is the data like  -->  select * from xyz_table          id
123
128
133
138
143
148
153
158

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question. As is, it's really hard to understand what you need.

Comment: <table>id
123
128
133
138
143
148
153
158

Comment: out put of xyz_table is                                                                                                                <table>id
552152345
552169362
552139618
552169286
550882912</table>

Comment: var1 var2 var3
552152345 2/1/2017 0:00 1000
552169362 8/1/2017 0:00 1000
552139618 7/1/2017 0:00 1000
552169286 5/15/2020 0:00 1000
550882912 10/1/2019 0:00 1000   above is the output of proc

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding informations in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Call_Date_Rate_Proc(var1) is a table function (pipelined or not), and you are on Oracle 12c, you can use the `CROSS APPLY`, `OUTER APPLY` or `LATERAL` joins features:

```
select *
  from xyz_table t1
 OUTER APPLY (select * from TABLE(Call_Date_Rate_Proc(t1.idx))) t2
 where t1.idx in (12100,78218);
```